# How to test mailer inside controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to check if my API method sends an email. Based on various threads on SO, i ended up with something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::IntervieweesController do
  before(:each) do
    @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
  end

  describe "POST /api/v1/interviewees/remind_code" do
    before(:each) do
      @interviewee = FactoryGirl.create(:interviewee, project: @project)
    end

    it "sends email with code" do
      post :remind_code, interviewee: { email: @interviewee.email }
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should == [@interviewee.email]
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is, `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` is allways `nil`, even if that method sends that email (when i'm running that method in a 'normal' way in my browser, outside of rspec tests). What's more interesting - it works fine in model specs. Do you have any idea what am i possibly doing wrong?

Rails v4
Ruby v2
rspec v3.0.0.beta1

**Please have in mind that the controller's action i'm testing above works fine and sends that email on production/development.**

Comment: Is your test env set with config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test?

Comment: Yes, it's set just like that.